# Seleção de radio button - Selenium e Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, radiobutton, xpath

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou tentando extrair uma informação do site do banco central usando selenium com python.
Primeiramente deixe-me explicar que, apesar de existir uma API para pegar o número da SELIC, a mesmo só envia duas casas decimais, então não serve pra mim.

O endereço é o seguinte: https://www.bcb.gov.br/htms/selic/selicacumul.asp?frame=1

Nele, o que preciso é:

1. Selecionar o radio button "Mensal";
2. O mês "passado" nos campos Mês e Ano;
3. Clicar no botão "Consultar";
4. Pegar a informação que for exibida em "Fator Acumulado";

Ao tentar realizar o primeiro passo...

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.bcb.gov.br/htms/selic/selicacumul.asp?frame=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/input').click()
```

Também já tentei por id e já tentei aguardar o carregamento, mas nada deu certo.

Segue erro que recebo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/input').click()
  File "C:\Users\joaoluistr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\joaoluistr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\joaoluistr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\joaoluistr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Obrigado antecipadamente pela ajuda, pessoal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecionando essa página você consegue ver que o conteúdo que você precisa acessar esta dentro de um IFrame, logo se você tentar acessar diretamente o Selenium nunca vai conseguir encontrar, mesmo com o full XPath do elemento

[image: DevTools]

Logo, você precisa falar pro seu Driver entrar no primeiro IFrame, caso existissem mais de um talvez especificar qual você precisa

```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/input").click()
    dropbox = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[6]/select"))
    dropbox.select_by_visible_text('Janeiro')
    #para usar o dropbox adicione from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: Perfeito, Ewerton. Obrigado!

Comment: poxa mas meu nome não é Ewerton kk